# A weired issue using RibbonButton's QuickAccess Toolbar

Tags: wpf, command, ribbon

I used Ribbon library for WPF for a big project. Now when I have a weired issue which is easy to create. Let's say I have a RibbonButton and set QuickAccessToolBarId property. It enables to add this button to the QuickAccessToolBar. The weired thing is that when I set ribbonButton.DataContext = ribbonButton; and add this button into the QuickAccessBar, it throws an stack overflow exception. I trace this issue into the library but no clue on this; I think some thing is implemented in the Microsoft.Windows.Shell assembly which I cannot step into.

I know it's not a normal way to use the DataContext, but I want to know what causes the stack overlay when adding the quick access bar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that stack overflow is caused because you are trying to set data context to the control itself. That is like you have recursively called some function and never get out of it.That way, you are creating infinite loop, and that causes stack overflow. It has nothing to do with QuickAccessToolBar.

Comment: I think it's one reason. But we can successfully set control to its own data context, please have a try if you are interesting. Only use quick access bar causes this problem; so that I think something is hard coded in the the event adding to that bar.

Comment: I have also used RibbonControl library and had problems with it. It is still not officially part of the framework... If you don't have latest version, try it, it solved many of my problems. [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2BFC3187-74AA-4154-A670-76EF8BC2A0B4&displaylang=en] But be aware that they removed RibbonCommand class from it, which is actually a good thing..

Comment: Actually, I'm using the October version. They enhanced the API a lot, but this issue still exists. I'm now transferring the ViewModel to another class instead of binding it self. I really want to know what exactly causes this issue. Thanks any way.